# optional htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

im working on a real estate site.

now, in the URL, i want there to be optional GET variables.

possible GET variables include:

> province (provinces in ontario)
>
> city (city in that province)
>
> type (house, apartment, condo, etc)
>
> price (100-200k, 200-300k, etc)
>
> bedrooms (1, 2, 3, 4, etc)
>
> bathrooms (1, 2, 3, 4, etc)

here is the URL structure i am thinking of:

mysite.com/p-ontario/c-toronto/house-listings/100-200k/1-bed/1-bath

now i want this to be interchangeable.

so the following URL's must work, no matter what order the GET variables are in it must always be able to grab them and use them to query listings:

> mysite.com/p-ontario/c-toronto/house-listings/100-200k/1-bed/1-bath
>
> mysite.com/p-ontario/house-listings/1-bed/1-bath
>
> mysite.com/p-ontario/c-toronto/100-200k
>
> mysite.com/p-ontario/house-listings/100-200k/1-bath
>
> mysite.com/p-ontario/100-200k/

can an HTACCESS pro please help me out and show me the best way to do this? please keep in mind that PROVINCE will ALWAYS be present, and will ALWAYS be the first GET variable in the URL after the .com.

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of Htaccess, otherwise out answers might not make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic Htaccess for what you want:

```
# Just Province
RewriteRule ^p-([a-z0-9]+)/?$ page.php?provinces =$1 [L,NC]

# Province and City
RewriteRule ^p-([a-z0-9]+)/c-([a-z0-9]+)/?$ page.php?provinces =$1&city=$2 [L,NC]

# Province, City and Listing
RewriteRule ^p-([a-z0-9]+)/c-([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)-listings/?$ page.php?provinces =$1&city=$2&type=$3 [L,NC]

# Province, City, Listing, Price
RewriteRule ^p-([a-z0-9]+)/c-([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)-listings/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ page.php?provinces =$1&city=$2&type=$3&price=$4 [L,NC]

# Province, City, Listing, Price, Beds
RewriteRule ^p-([a-z0-9]+)/c-([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)-listings/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)-bed/?$ page.php?provinces =$1&city=$2&type=$3&price=$4&beds=$5 [L,NC]

# Province, City, Listing, Price, Beds, Bathrooms
RewriteRule ^p-([a-z0-9]+)/c-([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)-listings/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)-bed/([0-9]+)-bath/?$ page.php?provinces =$1&city=$2&type=$3&price=$4&beds=$5&bathrooms=$6 [L,NC]
```

Instead of adding extra Htaccess to account for the optional city and price, you could just pass `any`:

```
mysite.com/p-ontario/c-any/house-listings/any/1-bed/1-bath
```